# How hard is the ISTQB Foundation Level Certification Exam?

Tags: istqb

I've gone over SQE's ISTQB-FL course twice and have read the official ISTQB-FL syllabus (and plan to read it again), but I'm still very nervous about taking the exam. Some of the sample exams I've taken have had extremely tricky/difficult questions. Some of them even have questions with terms that aren't in the syllabus (e.g., McCabe's Cyclomatic Complexity). At this point I'm thinking that I'll have to say screw it and just schedule and take the real thing, because the sample exams obviously aren't a true example of the real test.

Can anyone who's taken this test (passed or failed) give me some input? It would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Regarding how hard it is - pass rate is ~74%: http://www.istqb.org/exams-root/exam-questions-and-pass-rates.html

Answer (score 4):

I have taken this exam and in first attempt I scored 92.5% marks, so its not a very difficult exam. You just need to download the syllabus from ISTQB website and study all the topics for around 1 month. No need to study anything from outside. The syllabus is enough.

When you will appear in the exam you will find that almost all the questions you have read somewhere in that syllabus, so you will be easily able to answer all the question. I would like to say don't hesitate and prepare for it. It is simple and also good for preparing a strong base for software testing concepts.

Best of luck :)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've scheduled to take the exam this Friday and I am going over the syllabus for the second time. Your input makes me more confident!

Comment: Hey how was your xam, Christian?
Did the above suggestion helped you..